# OKHttp 2.2.0 - Abstract method not implemented

Tags: android, okhttp

When I use OKHttp to call web-services, I sometimes have a crash with the following stack trace :

`System.err(12651): java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method not implemented 
System.err(12651): at com.test.BaseService$3.onFailure(BaseService.java) 
System.err(12651): at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:154) 
System.err(12651): at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33) 
System.err(12651): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
System.err(12651): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
System.err(12651): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) dalvikvm(12651): threadid=23: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler`

I'm doing a generic method to call WS like that :

```
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON_MEDIA_TYPE, jsonRequest); 
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).put(body).headers(buildHeaders(url)).build();                 OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient(); 
httpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() { 

@Override 
public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) { 
    handleError(e); 
}

@Override public void onResponse(Response response) { 
    handleResponse(response.code(), response.body()); 
} 
});
```

Do you have any idea why this crash happens ?

Thank you

Comment: can you post your full code

Comment: There is nothing else very important. Most of my WS calls are working. Sometimes, I don't know why, my app crashes with that error.
My class is abstract and is implemented by other classes. I tried to put the handleError and handleResponse either abstract or not, the result is the same. I even don't know if the problem is due to the onFailure method call or the handleError one.

Comment: where is your abstract method? which is implements the youjr callback<T> class.

Comment: Please confirm you're using the same version of OkHttp at build-time as you are at runtime.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. I was using two different versions of OKHttp. One from a external lib and another in my main application.

Thanks Jesse :)